# Grails reloading file watcher error

Tags: java, spring, grails

I am working on a grails project which is divided into multiple sub-projects (grails plugin projects) like -

- MainProject

  - Subproject1 (grails.plugin.location.'Subproject1' = "../Subproject1")
  - Subproject2 (grails.plugin.location.'Subproject2' = "../Subproject2")
  - Subproject3 (grails.plugin.location.'Subproject3' = "../Subproject3")

Now the problem is that, When I edit any file in the Main project for example some controller or service, then Grails reloads the changes as and when I save it. BUT when I try to do the same in the SubProject it throws me with the following error and never reloads it so I need to stop and restart the project after every change.

**Note**:

- I am using IntelliJ Idea but I have tried it on Grails command line as well so it is not due to IDE.
- I have also tried Reinstalling Grails (2.4.4) which does not make any difference so again my Grails installation is not corrupted! Checked.
- I was using Java 1.8.0_31 but switching to Java 1.7.0_79 does not make any difference.

**Error**-

```
Error java.lang.IllegalStateException: No file extensions list found for path not being watched
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.WatchServiceDirectoryWatcher.run(WatchServiceDirectoryWatcher.java:87)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:154)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectWatcher.run(GrailsProjectWatcher.java:161)
| Error     at java_lang_Runnable$run.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProcess.startProjectWatcher(ForkedGrailsProcess.groovy:748)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1152)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProcess$_setupReloading_closure17.doCall(ForkedGrailsProcess.groovy:737)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProcess$_setupReloading_closure17.doCall(ForkedGrailsProcess.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:504)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
WARNING: There was an error setting up reloading. Changes to classes will not be reflected: No file extensions list found for path not being watched
```

Comment: Disable forked mode in your main application. That always seems to fix issues like this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this did not work for me in this. I did `grails.project.fork = [........   run: false, .....................]`

Comment: actually try commenting out the entire entry for `run` so it won't run in forked mode at all.